# Routes priority in Express: am I doing it wrong?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm a bit confused about the Express priority order for all the routes.
This is what I've done following some stackoverflow answers and other guides on internet.

I have some http requests and this is the order: is it right in your opinion? If not, why? Thanks!

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   ...
});

app.get('/:car', (req, res) => {
   ...
});

app.get('/:car/:eng', (req, res) => {
   ...
});

app.put('/:car/:feature_id', (req, res) => {
   ...
});

app.get('/import/colors', (req, res) => {
   ...
});

app.post('/import/brands', (req, res) => {
   ...
});

app.post('/import/colors/:car_id', (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Route should be from most specific to least specific. This is because the least specific one will always match, hence you will never be able to reach the most specific one otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Express just attempts to match your routes in the order they are defined in your code for the type of request it is (.e.g GET, POST, PUT).  So, if it's a GET request, Express matches only against the route definitions that include GET.  Here's a few examples from the routes you show.

If there's an incoming route of `/hello/there`, then that will first match `app.get('/:car/:eng', ...)` because that matches ANY two segment path and it's the first route in order that matches.

If there's an incoming route of `/import/colors`, then that will also match `app.get('/:car/:eng', ...)` because that matches ANY two segment path.

If, on the other hand, you change the order of the code to this:

```
app.get('/import/colors', (req, res) => {
   ...
});

app.get('/:car/:eng', (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

Then, `/import/colors` will match the first of these two routes because matching is tried in the order the routes are declared.

FYI, in general, I don't like using routes that have a top level wildcard because you get yourself all sorts of possible conflicts and you may find yourself boxed into a bit of a corner for future URL expansion when you want to add other routes.

**Recommendation**

So, if you have overlapping route definitions, then define the most specific routes first so they get a chance to match before the more general routes.  Most of the time, I prefer a URL design that doesn't have overlapping routes and then you won't have this issue at all.